# Rails testing authentication with has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, minitest

Per the title, I'm setting `session[:user_id]` in my controller if a user is authenticated successfully and then am testing that the session value matches the user id, but the session is nil with the following setup:

sessions_controlller.rb:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.find_by username: params[:username]
    if user.try(:authenticate, params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to user_posts_path, notice: "Successfully logged in!"
    else
      redirect_to new_session_path, alert: "Invalid credentials."
    end
  end
end
```

session_controller_test.rb:

```
test "should sign in user with correct credentials" do
  user_to_log_in = users(:one)
  post :create, { password: "password", username: "yes" }
  assert_equal user_to_log_in.id, session[:user_id]
end
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
end
```

users.yml:

```
one:
  id: 1
  username: yes
  password_digest: <%= BCrypt::Password.create('password', cost: 4) %>
```

How do I write a passing test here?

Answer (score 0):

You may not necessarily have access to server data, like session, in your tests. Check out rack_session_access https://github.com/railsware/rack_session_access for a possible answer.

Comment: This doesn't solve it, and according to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-four-hashes-of-the-apocalypse the session hash should be available after requesting a path.

Answer (score 0):

Hah, so apparently, with a username of 'yes' in users.yaml, the record in the test DB gets saved with a username of 't', so I assume it tries to convert it to some form of 'true'... Anyway changing the username in the fixture fixed the problem.